# React Native Android remote push notifications not showing up

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, pubnub

I am using the `react-native-push-notification` package and PubNub push notifications to handle the remote notifications. This all works on iOS just fine and I'm getting the notification data coming in from the `onNotification` method on android but there is no actual notification popping up on the screen as I would expect. Am I missing a configuration on the FCM side maybe or a specific permission check I need to ask for to make sure remote notifications can be shown on android devices?

I've followed the manual steps on the `react-native-push-notification` package to a T and triple checked I didn't miss something

Comment: Probably not a PubNub issue since PubNub doesn't handle the display of the notification on the client device. And it sounds like you are using the right FCM type (`notification`, not `data`) but review this KB article, [Why are my FCM push notifications not working?](https://support.pubnub.com/support/solutions/articles/14000088965-why-are-my-fcm-push-notifications-not-working-), to be sure all is in order. Also, can you share your published message payload here?

Comment: copied my test notification payload from somewhere else, it had some sort of `title_for_mobile` prop instead of `message` which I found later

Comment: So, did you resolve your issue? If not, can you share the message payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This GCM bit I was passing to Pubnub was this

```
"pn_gcm": {
    "data": {
      "title_for_mobile": "George Washingtons's phone has moved outside of the group",
      "summary_for_mobile": [ "George Washingtons's phone has moved outside of the group" ],
      "data": {
        "action": "radiusTrigger",
        "userId": 6,
        "groupId": 8
      }
    }
  }
```

and the `title_for_mobile` wasn't sending it to my phone as a push notification so I had to change it to

```
"pn_gcm": {
    "data": {
      "message": "George Washingtons's phone has moved outside of the group",
      "data": {
        "action": "radiusTrigger",
        "userId": 6,
        "groupId": 8
      }
    }
  }
```

And now it shows the notification on android